# Android com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, alarmmanager, android-syncadapter, amazon-cognito

So I am pretty new to Android development and AWS. I am doing a project in my spare time and have been dealing with an issue for the past month now and it is really really getting to me now.

Main focus for the application is it does a few checks in the background and then submits the data to AWS DynamoDB.

I started off by having an periodic Alarm Manager in my application and then pushing the data to DynamoDB. This worked perfectly fine until the application is forced closed, then when the Alarm goes off at time X, it gives me the following exception : 
com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool.

I then tried setting up a SyncAdapter. I have authentication going through Android Account Authentication anyway and DynamoDB accessed through the ContentProvider. Now I just setup my SyncAdapter. Again, data goes to Dynamo fine if the application is running or in the background and the sync executes. If I force close the application and then the sync executes it gives me these errors :

This error when the sync starts up -

E/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Failure to get credentials
                                                                                              com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Access to Identity 'eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' is forbidden. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

Followed by this when I tried to an insert to Dynamo -
 com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

Now from reading up on a few things, SyncAdapter is actually what I should be using. So I would like to continue with SyncAdapter, I just gave the example of Alarm Manager in case someone suggests it to me.

I have tried a huge amount of stuff really and nothing is working... it just seems like the SyncAdapter cant re-authenticate.

I have used the following main sources for the application : 
1 : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/tutorial-android-aws-mobile-notes-data.html
2 : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/integrating-amazon-cognito-with-the-android-accountmanager-api/

Plus a ton of others since some of the documentation above is obsolete at this point.

Comment: Hi, Have you configured any Authentication provider in your Cognito identity pool? If you haven't configured any authenticated provider, you need to check the "Unauthenticated access" checkbox when you created the Identity Pool? Can you verify this on the Amazon Cognito Console?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Does this not mean that a user can access my AWS infrastructure without being logged in?

Comment: yes, this means that a user can access backend without logging in. If you want the user to log in first, you will need to federate the auth token with pool before making SDK reqeusts.

Comment: So I have a Cognito user pool. So users need to sign in/up before accessing the application. I'm wondering though, when the application dies, is there a way I can get my sync adapter to get a new auth token and continue working?

Comment: It works when I set it to Unauthenticated access for the identity pool but I don't feel like that is ideal...